# and thus entering they occupied

Tags: adverbs

This is a sentence from Chapter 3 of *Guns, Germs and Steels*:

> These Indian squadrons began to enter the plaza to the accompaniment of great songs, and thus entering they occupied every part of the plaza.

How should I understand **and thus entering they occupied...**

*thus*, here, should mean like that or in that way, but why did *entering* follow *thus*?

Comment: Hello, Kiki. It's old-fashioned language, and arguably a redundancy here. It can be paraphrased 'These Indian squadrons began to enter the plaza to the accompaniment of great songs, and entering the plaza to the accompaniment of great songs they occupied every part of the plaza.' I'd drop the repeated info and write 'To the accompaniment of great songs' these Indian squadrons began to enter the plaza. They filled every part of the plaza.' (The troops filling the farthest reaches could hardly be claimed to still be 'entering'.) // If one uses 'thus entering',  'thus fulfilling the regulations',

Comment: ... 'thus setting the factions against each other' ..., 'thus' always precedes the _ing_-word – usually immediately, though there may be an adverb/restricting modifier. 'thus really annoying her family' / 'thus hardly endearing herself to his mother'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, Edwin - it makes sense to me!

Answer (score 3):

I think "entering" should have been followed by a comma: "and thus entering, they occupied every part of the plaza."  "Thus entering" is an [absolute construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction).  It has the force of an adverbial subordinate clause.  Here, it is similar to saying "while entering in this fashion".

Answer (score -1):

As in:

These Indian squadrons began to enter the plaza to the accompaniment of great songs, and *consequently* they occupied every part of the plaza.

**thus**  [TDF](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/thus)

> therefore; consequently